# Delete all associated table's data in CAKEPHP 3 by one query

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have a table products and some tables joint with it by product_id. I want to delete all rows of this product_id from all others tables when a product delete from product table. Now how can doing it in convenience way?
I am trying like below:

```
$productTable = [
        'related_products',
        'quantities',
        'products_tags',
        'products_settings',
        'products_details',
        'categories_products',
    ];
    $tableObj = TableRegistry::get('Products');
    $query = $tableObj->query();
    $result = $query->deleteAll()
        ->contain($productTable)
        ->where(['store_id' => $storeId])
        ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Cakephp there is a dependent property to delete the associated data from other tables.

> When the dependent key is set to true, and an entity is deleted, the
>   associated model records are also deleted. In this case we set it to
>   true so that deleting a User will also delete her associated Address.

To use this just create your `association` and add `dependent` true. For e.g

```
/* In a Table's initialize method. */
$this->hasMany('Comments', [
    'dependent' => true,  /* Add this line */
]);
```

[Cake -> Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)

Comment: Cool, but doesn't work for me. I think that the reason may be that I explicitly set foreign keys in migration.